# Resposexml returns null value

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I am new to ajax. I wanted to create a simple webpage where it contains a button if clicked returns image dynamically.But the responseXML returns null value. Here is part of javascript code:

```
function process()
{
    if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 || xmlhttp.readyState==0)
    {
        xmlhttp.open("GET","image.php",true);
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = handleserverresponse;
        xmlhttp.send();
    }else{
        setTimeout('process()',1000);
    }
}

function handleserverresponse()
{
    if(xmlhttp.readyState==4){
        if(xmlhttp.status==200){    
            xmlResponse = xmlhttp.responseXML;
            imag = xmlResponse.documentElement.firstChild.data;
            document.getElementById("divimg").innerHTML=imag;
        }
        else{
            alert("something went wrong");
        }
    }
```

here is php code:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type:text/xml');
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>';

echo "<res>";
echo "<img src="a.jpg"/>";
echo "</res>";

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason responseXML was null because there is a mistake in PHP file.
I guess We cannot send HTML tags when content type is xml. Instead what we can do is echo source of image and modify JavaScript file to take that source and display using img tag.

Answer (score 0):

```
Your HTTP request is asynchronous. xmlhttp.responseXML won't have some value until xmlhttp.readyState has the value of 4.

var url = "http://localhost/xml.php?type=xml";
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
      xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else if (window.ActiveXObject)  {
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
if (xmlhttp) {
    xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
            alert(xmlhttp.responseXML);
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.send();
}
Additionaly, I don't think you need the setRequestHeader line. XML MIME type is required for response, not for request. Also, please respect good coding practices (don't forget var, DRY, etc.)
```

Comment: Did you just copied that code because in mine program readystate is already 4 as you can see. And I have seen almost same reply on another post.